# visitor design pattern error: "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python

I am trying to practice using the visitor design pattern, but I keep getting an error:

> CarVistor.visit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I am not sure why I am getting this error?

```
class Vehicle:
    def accept(self, VehicleVistor):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    def accept(self, vistor):
        vistor.visit(self)

class Motorcycle(Vehicle):
    def accept(self, vistor):
        vistor.visit(self)

class Vistor:
    def visit(self):
        pass

class CarVistor(Vistor):
    def visit(self):
        print("printing from car visitor")

class MotorcycleVistor(Vistor):
    def visit(self):
        print("printing from motorcycle visitor")


vehicle1 = Car()
vehicle2 = Motorcycle()

vistor1 = CarVistor()
vistor2 = MotorcycleVistor()

vehicle1.accept(vistor1)
vehicle2.accept(vistor2)
```

Comment: The `visit()` method needs another parameter for the vehicle being passed as an argument.

Comment: @Barmar oh that makes sense I didn't realize that in this line: vistor.visit(self) that self was considered to be another parameter. Thank you!

Comment: Of course it is. How else would it be passed? The `self` parameter in the function definition receives `vistor`.

Comment: @Barmar Would it make a difference in the design pattern if I removed it? so then it would just be like this: vistor.visit() I have updated the code in the question for reference

Comment: That works, too. But I assumed you were passing `self` for a reason.

Comment: @Barmar No, just trying to practice the design pattern. Thank you

Comment: Don't update the code in the question. Now it doesn't get the error you describe.

Comment: If you don't pass `self`, how will it know which vehicle it's being visited from?

Comment: **Please do not edit questions** to fix the problem that was being asked about. The code in a question needs to demonstrate the problem, so that people who read it later can understand how the problem is caused. Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel agreed my apologies

Comment: Sorry about rolling back my rollback, then rolling that back again as well. I got confused. This is a common issue but even experts need to pay attention sometimes :) Anyway, please see the linked duplicate. There is nothing special about the visitor pattern here; the underlying idea is that the instance upon which a method is called *already counts as an argument*, which should normally end up as the `self` value. Passing something else adds an argument and does not replace the method-call argument, *even if* "something else" happens to be named `self`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `self` argument (the first one) is automatically passed once you call a method on an object.

You should remove the `self` from the arguments list:

```
class Vehicle:
    def accept(self, VehicleVistor):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    def accept(self, vistor):
        vistor.visit()

class Motorcycle(Vehicle):
    def accept(self, vistor):
        vistor.visit()

class Vistor:
    def visit(self):
        pass

class CarVistor(Vistor):
    def visit(self):
        print("printing from car visitor")

class MotorcycleVistor(Vistor):
    def visit(self):
        print("printing from motorcycle visitor")


vehicle1 = Car()
vehicle2 = Motorcycle()

vistor1 = CarVistor()
vistor2 = MotorcycleVistor()

vehicle1.accept(vistor1)
vehicle2.accept(vistor2)
```

You can read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/) more about `self`.

---

> self is the first argument of every method in Python.
> When Python calls a method in your class, it will pass in the actual instance of that class that you're working with as the first argument.

> The self variable points to the instance of the class that you're working with.

From [Python's self](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/what-is-self/)

---

There are some cases that you might want to pass self as an argument to a method/function because `self` is just a pointer to the instance of the class.

---

For example if you want the `visit` method to have pointers of 2 objects (the one on which you called `visit` and another one), you need to add another argument to the args list:

```
class Vehicle:
    def accept(self, VehicleVistor):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    def accept(self, vistor):
        vistor.visit(self)

class Motorcycle(Vehicle):
    def accept(self, vistor):
        vistor.visit(self)

class Vistor:
    def visit(self):
        pass

class CarVistor(Vistor):
    def visit(self, visitor):
        print("printing from car visitor")

class MotorcycleVistor(Vistor):
    def visit(self, visitor):
        print("printing from motorcycle visitor")

vehicle1 = Car()
vehicle2 = Motorcycle()

vistor1 = CarVistor()
vistor2 = MotorcycleVistor()

vehicle1.accept(vistor1)
vehicle2.accept(vistor2)
```

Comment: It would actually be ok to pass `self` to `vistor.visit()` as a different arguement if `CarVistor.visit()` was defined as taking a 2nd parameter.  Then `self` in ``vistor.visit()` would be the vistor, while the `self` passed from `Car.accept() -> vistor.visit(self)`` would be the `Car` object.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Yes, you are right, I just tried to explain the reason for the error... I edited my answer to include that :)